# Checking element exist

Tags: python, selenium, web-crawler

I tryed use Selenium. Sometimes element which I check doesn't exist on this site. I want that default value will bw nonw, undefined or empty value. I tryed do that:

```
if browser.find_element_by_xpath("//span[contains(text(), 'Character')]/following::span"):
    character = browser.find_element_by_xpath("//span[contains(text(), 'Character')]/following::span").text
else:
    character = ''
```

I tryed with size too but any time Id browser is at site without Character field, my app stopped. How can I solve my problem?

Comment: Use try/except.

Comment: you can also use find_elements which would return a zero size array instead of throwing when the element is not found.

Answer (score 1):

use elements instead , as it will return empty array if no element is found.

you can use not to negate it

```
elements =browser.find_elements_by_xpath("//span[contains(text(), 'Character')]/following::span")
if elements:
    character = elements[0].text
else:
    character = ''
```

in python empty array equates to false so you can use that :

```
if []:
    print("not empty")
else:
    print("empty")
```

Comment: You can save the result of `find_elements_by_xpath` to the variable to look for it once and to avoid repeating yourself.

Comment: Updated it like that

Answer (score 1):

Just try to set character to a value otherwise to none.

```
try:
    character = browser.find_element_by_xpath("//span[contains(text(), 'Character')]/following::span")).text
except Exception as e: 
    print(e) 
    character = ''
```

Either

```
except NoSuchElementException:
```

Comment: Yeah you were kind of overengineering it a tad.

Comment: make sure to print the exception for debuggin when ever you use try catch ,

Comment: You should use more specific exception

Comment: That answer was to show how to use not and elements mostly

Comment: use except Exception as e:  print(e) @YevhenKuzmovych

Comment: You should use more specific exceptions. I believe `NoSuchElementException` in this case.